# Can a computer on one VLAN acquire DHCP from another VLAN?

Tags: dhcp, vlan

Can you please explain what needs to be done in order for a computer in one VLAN to get an IP from a DHCP server in another/different VLAN?

(Yes if something is done and no if that something is not done is all I know)

Comment: why you add vlan when you want to be in lan to use dhcp ?

Answer (score 2):

when a client requests an IP address it does not know anything about the DHCP server so it broadcasts a DHCP DISCOVER packet to all hosts on its segment, if it does not get a response - and it won't in your case - DHCP won't work, in order to avoid setting up an DHCP server in every VLAN we use 'IP HELPER' address, this is a switch configuration that detects DHCP DISCOVER and answers with the IP of the DHCP server.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-relay-agent.html

Comment: `we use 'IP HELPER' address, this is a switch configuration that detects DHCP DISCOVER and answers with the IP of the DHCP server` - That's not correct. A DHCP Relay Agent forwards the DHCP broadcast traffic as unicast traffic to the DHCP server on behalf of the DHCP client. The DHCP Relay Agent does not answer the client with the ip address of the DHCP server.

Comment: correct, - it doesn't actually change the DHCP protocol, the answer comes from the DHCP server via the switches 'pass it on' config.

Comment: ok so a DHCP Relay Agent forwards the DHCP broadcast traffic as unicast traffic to the DHCP server on behalf of the DHCP client, 

and how does the DHCP client gets an answer (or the IP address) then?

Does the Relay Agent forward the answer to the client from the server?